# how to use a method with no args in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I define a class `a` and a method `b`like this: (In Python2.7)

```
class a:
    def b():
        print("hello")
```

I can call this method neither by

```
 a.b()
```

nor:

```
a_instance = a(); a_instance.b()
```

My questions are:

(1) Is there a way to call b?

(2) Is there any situation that this usage is meanful?

(3) I think b is neither a `static method` nor a `instance method`. Is `b` a `class method`? If not, what should be named to `b`?

Comment: Why should a.b() work? Do you know what a class *instance* is? Otherwise learn about static methods.

Comment: What's the connection to Ruby?

Comment: No connection to Ruby, OP is confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or [`classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator which takes class object as first instance.

> Is there a way to call b?

Yes you could either make it a static method or an instance method and call it accordingly.  Below i make it a static method so you can call it on any instance or directly on the class object `a`

```
class a:
    @classmethod
    def b(cls):
        print("hello")

a.b() #'hello'
```

> Is there any situation that this usage is meanful?

What usage? static methods? yes there is, and it depends on your architecture.  classmethods can be used as factory functions? returning new instances of classes.

> I think b is neither a static method nor a instance method. Is b a class method? If not, what should be named to b?

i, too, don't think it is either.  I believe it is just a function defined inside of a class body

I was confused about defining a function inside of a class and asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600716/assigning-class-variable-dynamic-value-from-inside-a-classs)

Answer (score 2):

`b` is a static method. Just add the `@staticmethod` decorator.

```
class a:
    @staticmethod
    def b():
        print("hello")
```

Also, you shouldn't really do this, but if you wanted to call `b()` without changing the class, you could do `a().b.__func__()`.

Comment: I almost feel like downvoting for `a().b.__func__()` please don't suggest stuff like this.

Comment: I'm not suggesting it. I'm just explaining that it's possible. In fact, I explicitly said you *shouldn't* do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this isn't obvious:

```
class a:
   def b(self):   # a normal "instance method" -- note "self"
       print("hello")

aa = a()   #  an instance

aa.b()     # call with no parameters
```

Here, `b` has no parameters because `self` is implied when called on an instance of the class.